# FocusOut event triggering two callbacks instead of expected one in Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter, event-handling, widget

I'm using some code I found to create a timepicker widget for tkinter consisting of two Spinboxes (one for hour value and another for minutes value), but when I add behaviour for the  event on both spinboxes, both are being triggered with only one FocusOut event in only one Spinbox.

The expected behaviour would be that only the callback from the spinbox that lost focus should be triggered, not both.

**Edited**: After the comment by acw1668, now I know that the problem is that the messagebox Dialog steals the focus from the next Spinbox, so now I'm looking for a proper solution or good practice to solve this.

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Timepicker(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.hourstr = tk.StringVar(self, '10')
        self.hour = tk.Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=23, wrap=True, name='hourspin',
                               textvariable=self.hourstr, width=4)
        vcmd = (parent.register(self._validate_hour), '%P')
        self.hour.configure(validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.hour.bind('<FocusOut>', self._focus_hour)

        self.minstr = tk.StringVar(self, '30')
        self.minstr.trace("w", self.trace_var)
        self.last_value = ""
        self.min = tk.Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=59, wrap=True, name='minspin',
                              textvariable=self.minstr, width=4, )
        vcmd = (parent.register(self._validate_minutes), '%P')
        self.min.configure(validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.min.bind('<FocusOut>', self._focus_minutes)

        self.hour.grid()
        self.min.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def trace_var(self, *args):
        if self.last_value == "59" and self.minstr.get() == "0":
            self.hourstr.set(int(self.hourstr.get()) + 1 if self.hourstr.get() != "23" else 0)
        self.last_value = self.minstr.get()

    def _focus_hour(self, event):
        result = self._validate_generic(self.hourstr.get(), 23)
        if (not result or self.hourstr.get() == '') \
                and self.parent.focus_get() != '.!timepicker.hourspin':
            messagebox.showerror('Invalid value', f'{self.hourstr.get()} is not a valid input')

    def _focus_minutes(self, event):
        result = self._validate_generic(self.minstr.get(), 23)
        if (not result or self.minstr.get() == '') \
                and self.parent.focus_get() != '.!timepicker.minspin':
            messagebox.showerror('Invalid value', f'{self.minstr.get()} is not a valid input')

    def _validate_hour(self, new_value):
        # Returning True allows the edit to happen, False prevents it.
        if new_value == '':
            return True

        result = self._validate_generic(new_value, 23)
        return result

    def _validate_minutes(self, new_value):
        # Returning True allows the edit to happen, False prevents it.
        if new_value == '':
            return True

        result = self._validate_generic(new_value, 59)
        return result

    def _validate_generic(self, new_value, maxvalue):
        if not new_value.isdigit():
            return False

        return len(new_value) <= 2 \
                  and int(new_value) <= maxvalue

root = tk.Tk()
Timepicker(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is `self.min.bind('<FocusOut>', self._focus_minutes)` this where the problem is? Your binding it to `min` right? Where else would you want it? I dont see any two callbacks being triggered here

Comment: self.hour.bind('<FocusOut>', self._focus_hour) is the other callback

Comment: It is because when `self.min` loses the focus, `self.hour` gets the focus.  Then the `messagebox` is shown and make `self.hour` lose the focus which trigger the callback. Such behaviour will disappear if, for example, a button is added after `self.min`.  In this case, after `self.min` loses the focus, the button will get the focus which will not trigger the '<FocusOut>` event of `self.hour`.

Comment: So, the only solution here is adding some widget?

Comment: Actually what is the problem of two `<FocusOut>` callbacks be called?

Comment: Well, it is a timepicker, so if, for example, you clear hour and minutes and then enter a value for the hour Spinbox, both messages for both spinboxes appear. It's counter-intuitive and confusing. Also, not friensly

Comment: Actually you don't need the `<FocusOut>` binding because you have already used `validatecommand`.

Comment: Yes, but with validatecommand I need the spinboxes to allow to delete the Spinbox content and allow blank values in order to be editable by the user. Once that blank is allowed, I need FocusOut to control they are not leaving the Spinbox blank